# How to calculate the number of variables in the smali file during decompilation

Tags: python, smali

I've been bothered for a long time About How to calculate the number of variables in the smali file during decompilation
what i need is：One idea, one solution, one light bulb!

```
def parse_smali_field_num(smali_path):
    count = 0
    with open(smali_path, 'r', 4096, 'utf-8') as f:
        text = f.readline()
        if (not text.startswith('.class')):
            print('Warning:Not a class smali file:' + str(smali_path))
            return 0
        while (text):
            text = f.readline()
            if (text.startswith('.field')):
                count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code appears to want to count the number of lines in a text file that start with `'.field'`, but has some mistakes. Please be specific about the problem you are having. Can you provide the contents of a simply .smali file and show what results you get for that, and what you expected instead? (note  that if your question is "what is wrong with my code?", something like ChatGPT will have a pretty clear answer for you - please be specific about what problem you need help with here)